# Implementing Python function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to implement a function in Python that will sort a list of strings in reverse alphabetical order. Can someone help me with the code?

I've tried using the sorted() function in Python to sort my list of strings in reverse order, but I'm not sure if I'm using the correct syntax. Specifically, I expected to see the list sorted in reverse alphabetical order when I run my code, but the output doesn't match my expectations.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you provide us with what you've tried? You said that you're unsure if you're using the correct syntax, but that is a question you need to answer before trying to implement your function. Without any code, we can't help guide you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort a list of strings in reverse alphabetical order you can use the sort() method with the reverse argument set its value to reverse=True